# How many ways are there to stack m piles with n items?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How the calculate the number of ways (permutation) of stacking m piles with n items?

Let's say I want 2 piles with 3 items: How to caluculates the permutations? A pile can consist of no item. What's to be considered is, that there are 2 places where an item can be placed.  Legal combinations are:

```
o o    x o    o o    o x    
o x    x o    x o    o x    
x x    x o    x x    o x
```

Not allowed is (Gravity needs to be considered):

```
x x
o o 
x o
```

I thought catalan numbers could help. But I can't find a way to use them.

Comment: Are 2nd case and 4th case the same ? We have 1 empty pile and 1 pile of 3 in both cases.

Comment: $p_1+p_2+\cdots+p_m=n$ The solution is an application of "stars and bars"

Comment: @PhilippeMorin No, case 2 and 4 are not the same. Because we need to consider the number of places for a stack to build too.

Comment: @DanielMathias sounds promising. Will have a look at it.